# How to produce images using Spinner in Android Studio

Tags: android, imageview, spinner, android-spinner, android-studio-2.3

I am new in Android Studio, can somebody help me to produce images using Spinner?

Thanks for the tips and advice.

Comment: Please edit your question and explain **in detail** what "produce images using Spinner" means.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher, View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    EditText ed;
    CheckBox c;
    Spinner s1, s2;
    ToggleButton t;
    LinearLayout l;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed.addTextChangedListener(this);
        c = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        c.setOnClickListener(this);
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter adap = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.days1, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        s1.setAdapter(adap);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        String days[] = {"sunday", "monday", "tuesday"};
        s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ada = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, days);
        s2.setAdapter(ada);
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        t = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tb);
        l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        t.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "before", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"after",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        try {
            int no = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            if (no > 100) {
                s.replace(0, s.length(), "100");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox t = (CheckBox) v;
        if (t.isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coffee with sugar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coffee without sugar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (parent.getId() == R.id.spinner) {
            //Log.d("hi", "item selected");
            TextView txt = (TextView) view;
            Log.d("spin1", txt.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "u have selected" + txt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (parent.getId() == R.id.spinner1) {
            CheckedTextView txt1 = (CheckedTextView) view;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "u have selected" + txt1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("spin2", txt1.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            l.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            l.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.dhanya.edittextproject.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="enter percentage [75%]"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:maxLines="2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sugar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I want coffee with" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="change to dark color"
        android:textOn="change to light color" />
</android.widget.LinearLayout>
```

And here is the `strings.xml`

```
<resources>    
    <string name="app_name">EdittextProject</string>    
    <string-array name="days1">    
        <item>Blue</item>    
        <item>Green</item>    
        <item>Red</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```